# Ruby on rails: dependent destroy not working with renamed foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

*I didn't find any related threads on this, so I made a new question myself.*
I have following models. I added `foreign_key: :sender` in the class User because the field name `:sender` of the model class `Comment` differs from the model class `User`.
I added `dependent: :destroy` to the class `User` to make sure when an user is deleted all of its comments are deleted as well.
However when I destroy an user, their comments do not get destroyed. The comments remain in the database. I don't see why.

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :event
end

class User < ApplicationRecord     
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :sender
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
<snip>
def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id]) # dont mind this line
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to event_path(@event) # dont mind this either
  end
<snip>
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
<snip>
def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    redirect_to users_path
  end
<snip>
end
```

Comment: "this is not the case " - can you please be more specific/concrete. What code did you try to run on what data? What did you actually observe happening and what did you expect to see happening?

Comment: I edited my post. If things are still not clear, please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it by changing `foreign_key: :sender` to `foreign_key: :sender_id`. In other words, the real db column `:sender_id` has to be given instead of the field name `:sender`.

However, when I was using `foreign_key: :sender` before I did not get any errors from rails. It just did not the delete the comments when deleting an user.
If anyone can explain why I did not see any errors, I would like to hear from you.

Comment: Good on you for solving it. I have no clue why Rails didn't complain about the weird `sender` thing :/ what a strange reaction to that... might be worth reporting as an issue to rails... a more meaningful error would be better.